# Definition of Ideal in a Ring

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring *without unity*. Let $I$ be a non-empty subset of $R$ satisfying:

(1) $a,b\in I$ $\Longrightarrow$ $a+b\in I$.

(2) $a\in I$ and $r\in R$ $\Longrightarrow$ $r.a\in I$.

Is $I$ a (left) ideal of $R$?

---

One may assume if want that $R$ is commutative; the only thing I am considering here is writing condition (1) instead of the usual condition $a-b\in I$.

Comment: You juste have to show that $(I,+)$ is (or not) a subgroup of $(R,+)$, to conclude.

Comment: Under only condition (1), I may not be additive subgroup; but condition (2) may force it to become subgroup!

Comment: I realized that my response was missing (2), sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Take the ring $R=x\mathbb Z[x]$, consisting of polynomials with integer coefficients and constant coefficient zero. Consider the set $S=\mathbb Nx + x^2\mathbb Z[x]$, consisting of elements of $R$ with nonnegative $x$-coefficient. The set $S$ is clearly closed under addition, and multiplying an element of $R$ and an element of $S$ gives a multiple of $x^2$, which is an element of $S$. But $S$ is not closed under subtraction.